# Magento 2: values of multiselect attribute don't ever change!

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, configuration

i have a **multiselect** product attribute, that when ever i change its settings and save, i get

[image]

but the settings don't get changed. 
Here's the attribute's database values:

[image]

I'm on magento 2.2.4, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: any errors showing while saving ?

Comment: no errors in console nor in logs

Comment: I have (probably) the same problem - the value is saved in the database, but no options are selected in the product edit from in the Magento backend. Magento 2.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and fixed it using database. After a long R&D, I found that the same attribute values exist in both `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and `catalog_product_entity_text` tables.

You can check the all multiselect attributes from below query:

```
SELECT e.`attribute_id`,`attribute_code`,`frontend_input`,`backend_type`,`backend_model` FROM eav_attribute e LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` ce ON e.attribute_id = ce.attribute_id WHERE e.entity_type_id = 4 AND ce.is_visible = 1 AND e.frontend_input='multiselect'
```

For example, attribute id is **182**, so delete all entries from `catalog_product_entity_text` table where *attribute_id* is **182**.

Comment: Yes, I had to do manually change it in DB ...

Answer (score 0):

Login In your phpmyadmin
Select your website db
Open following table "eav_attribute"
Find attribute id "attribute_id"
Edit Row
If "backend_model" Column blank then paste this "Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend"